# Want to access the file uploaded using v-file-input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Actually I want user to upload a file from frontend and I want to send that file to server. I am using v-file-input but I dont know how to access the file once it is uploaded

```
<v-file-input type="file" label="Upload an image for your Avatar" prepend-icon="mdi-camera" @change="selectFile" ref="avatar"></v-file-input>
```

can someone tell me how can i access that file?

Comment: Give it a `$ref` and access the `files` object within

Comment: Thanks sir.. the issue got solved..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `v-model` prop.

```
<v-file-input v-model="myFileObject"></v-file-input>
```

The myFileObject contains either a single file object, or is an array of file objects. You can find more on the [v-file-input documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-file-input/#props).

You must also specify the myFileObject in your data.

```
data: () => ({
    myFileObject: null
})
```